# How to discover device properties and their powershell/WMI equivalent?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

I have this powershell code (I didn't write it) :

```
$nics = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "AdapterTypeID = '0' `
                                                    AND PhysicalAdapter = 'true' `
                                                    AND NOT Description LIKE '%Centrino%' `
                                                    AND NOT Description LIKE '%wireless%' `
                                                    AND NOT Description LIKE '%WiFi%' `
                                                    AND NOT Description LIKE '%Bluetooth%'"


foreach ($nic in $nics)
  {
  $nicName = $nic.Name
   ...
}
```

**Question**

How did the author knew that the NIC has those properties :

- Win32_NetworkAdapter
- AdapterTypeID
- PhysicalAdapter
- Description

In other words : How can I inspect all the properties that NIC/Other_Device has ?

Comment: Install Windows PowerShell ISE (or use get-member..)

Comment: @thebjorn I have it already installed. but I dont see how I can get access to device and properties in the first place.... can u please supply printscreen  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get-member` or (`gm`) gets you all properties:

```
PS C:\Users\bjorn> Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_NetworkAdapter

Name                        MemberType    Definition                                                                                        
----                        ----------    ----------                                                                                        
PSComputerName              AliasProperty PSComputerName = __SERVER                                                                         
Disable                     Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Disable()                                                  
Enable                      Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Enable()                                                   
Reset                       Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Reset()                                                    
SetPowerState               Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject SetPowerState(System.UInt16 PowerState, System.String Time)
AdapterType                 Property      string AdapterType {get;set;}                                                                     
AdapterTypeId               Property      uint16 AdapterTypeId {get;set;}                                                                   
AutoSense                   Property      bool AutoSense {get;set;}                                                                         
Availability                Property      uint16 Availability {get;set;}    
...
```

or with e.g. the ISESteroids plugin:

[image]

Comment: Hi. can u please guide me to a solution with this [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369285/how-can-i-get-all-window-handles-by-a-process-in-powershell) ?