# How can I get all window handles by a process in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have this script

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "*total*"}
```

Which yield this information

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                     
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                     
    362      23    19432      32744   324     3.86   6880 TotalCmd64
```

So I have the Process ID.

The `*Total*` application has many open windows of its own.

**Question**

How can I iterate ( using powershell)  through all its windows ( so I can get their window handle)  ?

NB : What is my goal ?

[image] :

Looking (for example ) at Visual studio : I have the application running.
but the application has its own open window .

I want the sub window to be TOPMOsT. I *already have* the script to make a window topmost. but I need its handle number.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you should check out WASP and see if it suits your needs: http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Secondly, I have modified code found here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c3cd3982-ffc5-4c17-98fc-a09c555e121c/get-all-child-window-titles?forum=winserverpowershell

to create a function that will take a MainWindowHandle as input, and will give you an object with child handle IDs back (It will also list any window titles, if any).

I hope one of these methods will give you what you need :)

```
function Get-ChildWindow{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [System.IntPtr]$MainWindowHandle
)

BEGIN{
    function Get-WindowName($hwnd) {
        $len = [apifuncs]::GetWindowTextLength($hwnd)
        if($len -gt 0){
            $sb = New-Object text.stringbuilder -ArgumentList ($len + 1)
            $rtnlen = [apifuncs]::GetWindowText($hwnd,$sb,$sb.Capacity)
            $sb.tostring()
        }
    }

    if (("APIFuncs" -as [type]) -eq $null){
        Add-Type  @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Text;
        public class APIFuncs
          {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd,StringBuilder lpString, int cch);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern Int32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd,out Int32 lpdwProcessId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);
            public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
            {
               List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
               GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
               try
               {
                   EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
                   EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc,GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
               }
               finally
               {
                   if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                       listHandle.Free();
               }
               return result;
           }
            private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
           {
               GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
               List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
               if (list == null)
               {
                   throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
               }
               list.Add(handle);
               //  You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
               return true;
           }
            public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);
           }
"@
        }
}

PROCESS{
    foreach ($child in ([apifuncs]::GetChildWindows($MainWindowHandle))){
        Write-Output (,([PSCustomObject] @{
            MainWindowHandle = $MainWindowHandle
            ChildId = $child
            ChildTitle = (Get-WindowName($child))
        }))
    }
}
}
```

You can pipe it directly from the result of Get-Process, like this:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq 'OUTLOOK'} | Get-ChildWindow
```

Comment: Thank you. I copied the text dump result from your code -   while window was open open (the solution explorer window).but when I closed the "solution explorer" window and compared the text to the old one - nothing changed.any ideas ?

Comment: Could it be that the handle is still active for a reason? Perhaps wait and try again? I don't really know how VS handles it's child processes and how often it frees memory etc. You could try to install a third party tool to verify that the output of my function is correct?