# How i can use GetWindowText API function in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How i can use GetWindowText API function in powershell ?

i tried this way :

```
    Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindowss {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);
}
"@
```

and i make string builder like this :

```
$stringbuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$stringbuilder.Capacity =256
```

i used function like :

```
$WindowTitless = $ImportDll::GetWindowText($TopWindow, $stringbuilder, 256)
```

but i got error :

```
ERROR: test: Failed to get active Window details. More Info: Exception calling "GetWindowText" with "3" argument(s): "Unable to find an entry point named
ERROR: 'GetWindowText' in DLL 'user32.dll'."
```

some one can give me help to use this function ? if you can please w**rite code** . tnx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all window handles by a process in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369285/how-can-i-get-all-window-handles-by-a-process-in-powershell)

Comment: FYI, you can get titles from Get-Process like:
Get-Process | where ProcessName -like 'notepad' | Select MainWindowHandle, MainWindowTitle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roughly this:

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindows {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);
}
"@

$stringbuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 256

Get-Process | ForEach-Object {

    $count = [UserWindows]::GetWindowText($_.MainWindowHandle, $stringbuilder, 256)

    if (0 -lt $count) {
        "$($_.ProcessName) $($stringbuilder.ToString())"
    }

}
```

You didn't say where `$ImportDll` came from in your code, but you need to be calling them as static methods on the class you defined.

The link in my close-vote has more complete examples in it.

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- [`Add-Type`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135195) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
- [`New-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113355) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
- [`Get-Process`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113324) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)
- [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)

Comment: tnx for your help . did you test your code? when i debug it count always = 0 . i want to get just windows text i need stringbuilder but nothing show here i vote your answers . tnx again

Comment: I ran it once. It returned window titles: http://i.imgur.com/oeLsFB0.png But I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Your solution works fine for me, PowerShell v5+ on my machine.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler : it's work tnx for your help .

Comment: i had problem in my computer . but your script work . tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can declare class with c# code and write your function in it then use it in your program .

```
    Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindowss {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);
}
"@
[UserWindowss]::GetWindowText(hwnd , stringbuilder , count)
```