# Bring child taskbar process to the foreground?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that starts a program with Start-Process with the -WindowStyle Minimized option, this program starts another process that appears as a child process in the task bar so in order to bring it to the front I need to click on it and select the proper window.

Now I am trying to have my script automatically bring the program to the front when a condition is met. I found the below method that works great when the process running in the taskbar does not have a child process. However, the child process that I want to bring to the front does not work with this method. If i use the parent process it will work.

```
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool 
ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
$hwnd = @(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "notepad"}) 
[0].MainWindowHandle
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 2)
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
```

Does anyone know how I could get this to work with the child taskbar process?

Comment: You'll probably have to PInvoke EnumChildWindows on the parent and then call the ShowWindow metgod on the specific hwnd of the child window.

Comment: I found this Get-ChildWindow function but it does not work for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369285/how-can-i-get-all-window-handles-by-a-process-in-powershell , Do you have any examples of the  EnumChildWindows method?