# How can I get the handle of each Firefox windows in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, firefox

I'm trying to get the handle of each windows opened by the firefox process. My use case is the following: on a computer in kiosk mode, I'm opening firefox at a specific URL with a powershell script at startup. That URL directs to an application that opens a new window that conveniently disable the use of the URL bar, preventing the user to browse the web. My problem is that the old window is still opened and I want to close it programmaticaly through that same powershell script. Although, the two windows have the exact same name so I can't use this to tell them apart.

I've tried listing the windows handles of the firefox process but it doesn't work since there is only one. I've also tried closing the main window of that process but since the pop up is coming up front, it's considered as the main window and so that is the windows that is closed.

There must be a way to select the correct window and close it because it is doable through the task manager.

edit: As a complement, I'd like to mention I tried what is mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369285/how-can-i-get-all-window-handles-by-a-process-in-powershell?rq=1) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The result of ```Get-Process firefox``` returns only one row in this scenario?

Comment: Yes it does. :(

Comment: I tried doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369285/how-can-i-get-all-window-handles-by-a-process-in-powershell?rq=1 and it doesn't work either by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to circumvent my issue by launching firefox as a hidden window. The pop-up then comes up correctly and I'm happy with the result.

```
$firefox = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList "https://myurl" -WindowStyle hidden
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Show-Process -Process $firefox
```